# Redirect site from www and non www to https

Tags: redirect, iis, url-rewriting

I have a rule to redirect my primary site to https and a test site to a test link as below

```
<rules>
    <rule name="One" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="*"/>
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="site.co.uk"/>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www.site.co.uk"/>
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.site.co.uk/{R:0}"/>
    </rule>
    <rule name="Two" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="*"/>
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^testing.domain.co.uk"/>
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="http://testing.domain.co.uk"/>
    </rule>
</rules>
```

I thought everything was working (each site was redirecting as required) until i ran a report and it seems if a user types in www.site.co.uk it displays the http version and not https - i have an entry for that `<add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www.site.co.uk"/>` which i thought was resolving this issue but it isnt.

How could i ensure my primary site with and without www can be redirected to the https version but also have my test site going to the test URL i have set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one mistake in your rule you forget to add the HTTPS pattern off because of that host www.site.co.uk is facing too many redirect errors.

Try below rule:

```
<rule name="One" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(.*)" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="www.site.co.uk|site.co.uk" />
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.site.co.uk/{R:0}" />
    </rule>
```

you no need to add the second rule.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this didnt work the way i was expecting it to. If i remove the second rule then my test site cant be reached. So i want rule 1 to redirect the combination of URLs above to the https site and rule 2 to redirect to a test site which is http. Thx

Comment: @Computer i tried this rule at my site which is working properly as you explained. i request you to clear your browser cache and history setting and try again to access your site. please check snapshot in my edited post.